# Scheduling a Python program to sleep within a given time period

Tags: python, linux, unix

```
while True:
      now = datetime.datetime.now();
      if now.hour >= 22 and now.hour < 3:
         print "sleep"
         sleep_at = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(),datetime.time(3))
         sleep_til = (sleep_at - now).seconds
         print sleep_til
         time.sleep(sleep_til)
         print "wake"
      else:
         print "break"
         break
```

This code should make my entire program to go to sleep at 10 PM and wake up at 3 AM. MY question is.. will this work? I tried running it.. but I cannot change my system/computer Time.. so I cannot check. 
Reason why I am posting this question is because my coding is using datetime.date.tday and datetime.datetime which is calling current date..

Once again.. I want my program to run before 10PM and sleep between 10PM to 3AM and rerun after 3AM..

Can someone check if this is the right way to do it?

Comment: If you cannot change the system time, then change the time in the code.

Comment: `if now.hour >= 22 and now.hour < 3:` will *never* evaluate to `True`.

Comment: You might be better off using cron, you should also compare to other datetimes, create start and end times and use those

Comment: @jedwards what do I need to change it to? so that it sleeps during 10 pm to 3 am ?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken sleep_at is also 3am of the current day, which I think you want 3am of the next. You might be looking for `datetime.timedelta`. You could try something like `sleep_at = now + datetime.timedelta(hours = 6)`

Comment: @DanielRobertson Yes that is the main reason why I asked this question.. but.. so that timedelta thing.. where should I place at?  or is only thing I need to change is replace my current sleep_at to your sleep_at? and why is hours = 6?

Comment: @PETER you were on the right track with `<timedelta>.seconds` -- see my answer for one approach that uses the same method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider (extra-verbose for clarity):

```
import time, datetime

# Create time bounds -- program should run between RUN_LB and RUN_UB
RUN_LB = datetime.time(hour=22)     # 10pm
RUN_UB = datetime.time(hour=3)      #  3am

# Helper function to determine whether we should be currently running
def should_run():
    # Get the current time
    ct = datetime.datetime.now().time()
    # Compare current time to run bounds
    lbok = RUN_LB <= ct
    ubok = RUN_UB >= ct
    # If the bounds wrap the 24-hour day, use a different check logic
    if RUN_LB > RUN_UB:
        return lbok or ubok
    else:
        return lbok and ubok


# Helper function to determine how far from now RUN_LB is
def get_wait_secs():
    # Get the current datetime
    cd = datetime.datetime.now()
    # Create a datetime with *today's* RUN_LB
    ld = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), RUN_LB)
    # Create a timedelta for the time until *today's* RUN_LB
    td = ld - cd
    # Ignore td days (may be negative), return td.seconds (always positive)
    return td.seconds


while True:
    if should_run():
        print("--do something--")
    else:
        wait_secs = get_wait_secs()
        print("Sleeping for %d seconds..." % wait_secs)
        time.sleep(wait_secs)
```

But I do agree that sleeping is not the best way to delay your program starting.  You may look into the task scheduler on Windows or `cron` on Linux.

Comment: I really don't understand your should_run part.. what does the last if and else do.. and how does that effect the while loop at the end?

Comment: `should_run()` returns a boolean value -- either `True` or `False`.  Nothing else.  It returns `True` if the current time is within the `RUN_LB`,`RUN_UB` bounds and `False` otherwise.  The last `if` statement is required in case you later change your bounds to something that *doesn't* wrap the 24-hour clock -- for example `RUN_LB = datetime.time(hour=1)` and `RUN_UB =  datetime.time(hour=5)` -- in that case you'd need to ensure that the current time met *both* conditions.  Since your bounds wrap the clock, *only one* condition needs to be met.

Comment: at should_run(); method, it retuns lbok or ubok else lobk and ubok what does this do? and lbok=RUN_LB <= ct... never seen this type of coding before.. can you explain little bit please?

Comment: `lbok` and `ubok` are booleans.  `lbok = RUN_LB <= ct` is the same as saying `if RUN_LB <= ct then lbok = True else lbok = False` -- same for the definition of `ubok`.  `lbok` stands for "Lower Bound OK" and `ubok` stands for "Upper Bound OK".  They are just booleans, signifying whether the current time (`ct`) falls inside the specified bound.  When the bounds *don't* cross the 24 hour day, then for a time to be between the lower and upper bound, it needs to meet **both** conditions -- in other words, both `lbok` and `ubok` must evaluate to `True` (cont'd)...

Comment: However, when the bounds cross the 24 hour day, **meeting both conditions is impossible**.  If the start time (lower bound) is 22 and the end time (upper bound) is 3, there are no times that are > 22 **and** < 3.  So instead, we modify the logic.  A time is considered to be in that 22-3 timeframe if it meets *either* condition.  A time has to be *either* > 22 **or** < 3.  If a time meets one of those conditions, then it's within the window we want to be running.  So at the end of the day, `should_run()` returns a boolean based on whether we're in the (start time, end time) timeframe.

Comment: okay I got the concept and I tried the coding with different time.. it looks like it is working.. but once again.. i can't test that next day time thing.. however, when i try to add one more statement, it is not working. at while loop inside of the if loop, I added 1if (now.hour >= 9 and now.hour <= 18: sys.exit(0)`

Comment: so I need to run this after working hour which is 6 pm and sleep at 10pm to 3am and run again until 9am and after 9am, I have to finish the program.. not killing it but stoping it..so it should finish up  the current file and even if there are more things to run i want to stop it..

Comment: i tried many different ways.. but i realized your original coding doesnt work either.. it should not work only between 10 pm to 3 am.. but it doesn't work all the time..

Comment: @PETER, I'm sorry if I haven't been clear or if you're not understanding the code, but absolutely does work, exactly as I said (I just tried it again)

Comment: I found the solution to your program.. at the if and else statement on the bottom.. I just need to change that.. if loop should do the sleep thing.. and else loop should break out and run the program